# Clojure edn read auto namespaced keywords

Tags: clojure, edn

Is there a way to instruct `clojure.core.edn/read` how to resolve auto namespaced keywords ?

```
  (edn/read-string "{:not-namespaced \"ko\" }") ;;=> {:not-namespaced "ko"}
  (edn/read-string "{:namespaced/ok \"ko\" }")  ;;=> #:namespaced{:ok "ko"}
  (edn/read-string "{::namespaced \"ko\" }")    ;;=> Unhandled java.lang.RuntimeException Invalid token: ::namespaced autonamespaced does not work
```

The last exception makes sense, since ["A keyword cannot begin with ::"](https://github.com/edn-format/edn).

I could use `load-file` with this simple example, however I also need the extensibility of `edn` (read custom tags).

Having a parameter to instruct how to resolve namespaces would make my config files (coerced with `clojure.spec`) much more readable.

Comment: Have you tried using `clojure.core/read-string`?

Comment: @OlegTheCat interesting, I did not ! I have to dig in it's options map though.

Comment: @OlegTheCat so as far as I understand it now, clojure.core/read-string will not allow me to have readers like in edn. This will prevent me from having configuations defined as in https://github.com/juxt/aero (could have worked otherwise).

Comment: @nha Perhaps [`tools.reader`](https://github.com/clojure/tools.reader) can do what you need? I haven't used it myself, though, so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my case it turn out the simplest solution is to use clojure.spec with un-namespaced keywords in my config file (I did not know it could do that).

Using the core readers functions would have worked too.

Quote from Alex Miller on slack:

> Yes, you'll need full namespaces in edn config files You could also
>   write specs on unqualified keys with req-un and opt-un
>
> Either the normal core reader fns or clojure.edn reader fns should be
>   able to read tagged literals though with #   You just need to bind
>   around the call to set up the readers

Answer (score 0):

I like to transform the string before parsing it in order to keep the edn files clean without having to treat the spec keys as unqualified.

```
(-> "{::namespaced \"ko\" }"
    (#(string/replace % #"::" ":some.namespace/"))
    (edn/read-string))
```

This may not be very robust when writing and re-reading edn files, but it works nicely for configuration data.